# TensorFlow: 2 layer feed forward neural net

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement a simple fully-connected feed-forward neural net in TensorFlow (Python 3 version). The network has 2 inputs and 1 output, and I'm trying to train it to output the XOR of the two inputs. My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, 2])
desired_outputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, 1])

weights_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2, 3]))
biases_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 3]))
layer_1_outputs = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(inputs, weights_1) + biases_1)

weights_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([3, 1]))
biases_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 1]))
layer_2_outputs = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(layer_1_outputs, weights_2) + biases_2)

error_function = -tf.reduce_sum(desired_outputs * tf.log(layer_2_outputs))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(error_function)

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

training_inputs = [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
training_outputs = [[0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0]]

for i in range(10000):
    train_step.run(feed_dict = {inputs: np.array(training_inputs), desired_outputs: np.array(training_outputs)})

print(sess.run(layer_2_outputs, feed_dict = {inputs: np.array([[0.0, 0.0]])}))
print(sess.run(layer_2_outputs, feed_dict = {inputs: np.array([[0.0, 1.0]])}))
print(sess.run(layer_2_outputs, feed_dict = {inputs: np.array([[1.0, 0.0]])}))
print(sess.run(layer_2_outputs, feed_dict = {inputs: np.array([[1.0, 1.0]])}))
```

It seems simple enough, but the print statements at the end show that the neural net is nowhere near the desired outputs, regardless of number of training iterations or learning rate. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

**EDIT**:
I've also tried the following alternative error function:

```
error_function = 0.5 * tf.reduce_sum(tf.sub(layer_2_outputs, desired_outputs) * tf.sub(layer_2_outputs, desired_outputs))
```

That error function is the sum of the squares of the errors. It ALWAYS results in the network outputting a value of exactly 0.5-- another indication of a mistake somewhere in my code.

**EDIT 2**:
I've found that my code works fine for AND and OR, but not for XOR. I'm extremely puzzled now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several issues in your code. In the following I'm going to comment each line to bring you to the solution.

Note: XOR is not linearly separable. You need more than 1 hidden layer.

N.B: The lines that starts with `# [!]` are the lines where you were wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# a batch of inputs of 2 value each
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])

# a batch of output of 1 value each
desired_outputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

# [!] define the number of hidden units in the first layer
HIDDEN_UNITS = 4 

# connect 2 inputs to 3 hidden units
# [!] Initialize weights with random numbers, to make the network learn
weights_1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, HIDDEN_UNITS]))

# [!] The biases are single values per hidden unit
biases_1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([HIDDEN_UNITS]))

# connect 2 inputs to every hidden unit. Add bias
layer_1_outputs = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(inputs, weights_1) + biases_1)

# [!] The XOR problem is that the function is not linearly separable
# [!] A MLP (Multi layer perceptron) can learn to separe non linearly separable points ( you can
# think that it will learn hypercurves, not only hyperplanes)
# [!] Lets' add a new layer and change the layer 2 to output more than 1 value

# connect first hidden units to 2 hidden units in the second hidden layer
weights_2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([HIDDEN_UNITS, 2]))
# [!] The same of above
biases_2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))

# connect the hidden units to the second hidden layer
layer_2_outputs = tf.nn.sigmoid(
    tf.matmul(layer_1_outputs, weights_2) + biases_2)

# [!] create the new layer
weights_3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, 1]))
biases_3 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

logits = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(layer_2_outputs, weights_3) + biases_3)

# [!] The error function chosen is good for a multiclass classification taks, not for a XOR.
error_function = 0.5 * tf.reduce_sum(tf.sub(logits, desired_outputs) * tf.sub(logits, desired_outputs))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(error_function)

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

training_inputs = [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]]

training_outputs = [[0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0]]

for i in range(20000):
    _, loss = sess.run([train_step, error_function],
                       feed_dict={inputs: np.array(training_inputs),
                                  desired_outputs: np.array(training_outputs)})
    print(loss)

print(sess.run(logits, feed_dict={inputs: np.array([[0.0, 0.0]])}))
print(sess.run(logits, feed_dict={inputs: np.array([[0.0, 1.0]])}))
print(sess.run(logits, feed_dict={inputs: np.array([[1.0, 0.0]])}))
print(sess.run(logits, feed_dict={inputs: np.array([[1.0, 1.0]])}))
```

I increased the number of train iteration to be sure that the network will converge no matter what the random initialization values are.

The output, after 20000 train iteration is:

```
[[ 0.01759939]]
[[ 0.97418505]]
[[ 0.97734243]]
[[ 0.0310041]]
```

It looks pretty good.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough answer. I understand the changes you made. However, I'm trying to perform the XOR operation, not the OR operation. So there actually was no mistake in my target outputs; the target outputs are [[0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0]]. Using your code, I still cannot get the neural network to perform XOR. Can you offer any help regarding that?

Comment: Thank you. I was actually able to achieve the goal with only 2 layers. Your idea of initializing the weights to non-zero values is what made my code work.

Comment: It is true that XOR is not linerarly separable and that you need a Multilayer perceptron; however, having 1 hidden layer already counts as being "multi-layer" (the other layer is the output). It is not necessary to have 2 hidden layers, indeed the author of the question managed to make it work with only 2 layers (1 hidden, 1 output).

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation looks correct. Here are a few things you could try:

- Change `tf.nn.sigmoid` to other non-linear activation functions
- Use a smaller learning rate (1e-3 to 1e-5)
- Use more layers
- Follow the [XOR neural network architecture](http://mnemstudio.org/neural-networks-multilayer-perceptrons.htm)

Comment: I tried your suggestions; no success. I would like to add that, after training, all inputs result in very similar outputs (ie. 00, 01, 10, and 11 all result in the neural net outputting ~0.77). Since it's a simple fully-connected network, more layers in this case won't yield any additional capability or accuracy, so I'd like to avoid that. I've also implemented this exact neural net in MATLAB before, and it worked, so I feel confident that I've simply made a mistake in my code somewhere.

Comment: In `error_function` don't directly multiply the desired outputs but instead subtract the values. Also try converting it into a Euclidean loss.  Alternatively, you could frame this as a classification instead of a regression problem.

Comment: I tried a more conventional error function (see my edit of the original post) involving the difference between the target and the output, instead of the cross entropy. However, I'm still experiencing incorrect behavior.